# How to update object properties in a AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I've uploaded nearly 25k files (large media files) to an s3 bucket. I used AWS SDK2 for PHP (`S3Client::putObject`) to perform uploads. Now, I need to update metadata for these files i.e change the ContentDisposition to attachment and assign a filename.

Is there a way to perform this without requiring to re-upload the file? Please help.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? The only thing I see that comes close is `copyObject`.

Comment: @dsummersl Yes, copyObject is the only way out as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [copyObject method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_copyObject), where you set the `CopySource` parameter equal to the `Bucket` and `Key` parameters.

Example:

```
// setup your $s3 connection, and define the bucket and key for your resource.
$s3->copyObject(array(
  'Bucket' => $bucket,
  'CopySource' => "$bucket/$key",
  'Key' => $key,
  'Metadata' => array(
    'ExtraHeader' => 'HEADER VALUE'
  ),
  'MetadataDirective' => 'REPLACE'
));
```

Comment: I've not tried the CopySource. So, I'll have to do a Copy and then Delete old one. I'm going to try this.

Comment: Ok. Finally here is how I used a mix of copyObject and deleteObject to achieve the goal.

1. Copy the original object with updated meta tags to a temp folder.
2. Remove original.
3. Copy temp to original location.
4. Remove the copy from temp location.

Too much of effort for something such simple. Unfortunately, no alternate method with PHP SDK.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

#### For delete existing object

```
$keyname = 'product-file/my-object1.dll';
try
{
  $delete = $this->s3->deleteObject([
    'Bucket' => 'belisc',
    'Key'    => $keyname
  ]);

  if ($delete['DeleteMarker']){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
catch (S3Exception $e) {
  return $e->getAwsErrorMessage();
}
```

#### For check object

return **true** if object is still exists

```
$keyname = 'product-file/my-object1.dll';
try {
  $this->s3->getObject([
    'Bucket' => 'belisc',
    'Key'    => $keyname
  ]);

  return true;
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
  return $e->getAwsErrorMessage();
}
```

#### Then you can upload the new one

```
try {
  return $this->s3->putObject([
    'Bucket' => 'belisc',
    'Key'    => 'product-file/MiFlashSetup_eng.rar',
    'SourceFile' => 'c:\MiFlashSetup_eng.rar'
  ]);
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
  die("There was an error uploading the file. ".$e->getAwsErrorMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Update Cache Control Metadata on S3 Objects

```
<?php
define('S3_BUCKET', 'bucket-name');
define('S3_ACCESS_KEY', 'your-access-key');
define('S3_SECRET_KEY', 'secret-key');
define('S3_REGION', 'ap-south-1'); //Mumbai

require 'vendors/aws/aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

try {
    $s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
                'version' => 'latest',
                'region' => S3_REGION,
                'credentials' => array(
                    'secret' => S3_SECRET_KEY,
                    'key' => S3_ACCESS_KEY,
                )
    ));

    $objects = $this->s3->getIterator('ListObjects', array('Bucket' => S3_BUCKET));

    echo "Keys retrieved!\n";
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        echo $object['Key'] . "\n";
        $s3->copyObject(array(
            'Bucket' => S3_BUCKET,
            'CopySource' => S3_BUCKET . '/' . $object['Key'],
            'Key' => $key,
            'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg',
            'ACL' => 'public-read',
            'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
            'CacheControl' => 'max-age=172800',
            'MetadataDirective' => 'REPLACE'
        ));
    }
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

Comment: How is it different from current answer?